# 2013 Honda Accord iow beam headlights not working

Tags: honda

My 2013 Honda Accord low beam headlights ( both ) stopped working but my high beams work and fog lights work.

Comment: Have you checked the bulbs? What specifically is your question?

Answer (score 1):

For both to fail at the same time means it's unlikely to be a regular bulb failure (not impossible, but unlikely).

So with that in mind I would suggest it is likely to be either the fuse or the relay, both are located in the engine bay fuse box which is located near the brake fluid reservoir. The underside of the fuse box lid should provide a map to which is which.